# malloc with structs and how to access memory of malloc of struct

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc

if i have a simple struct such as
How would i got about dynamically allocating memory for this struct using malloc?

```
struct Dimensions{
int height, width;
char name;
};
```

I um unsure on how to go about this, I have tried

```
struct Dimension* dim = malloc(sizeof(struct Dimensions));
```

Also I would like then access the height and width variable in a loop later on in my code. My first thought would be to use a pointer but im unsure on what this would exactly be.

Would it be something like

```
int h = *width
```

I'm very new to C. Thanks

Comment: `dim->height`, `dim->width` and `dim->name` -- `dim` is a pointer so you use the `->` operator to reference members. If `dim` were NOT a pointer, but a declaration of type `struct Dimension` itself, then you would use the `.` operator to access the members.

Comment: Assuming that `char name` would contain more than one character, you better change its definition to `char *name` (a pointer, pointing to a collection of characters, sized dynamically) or `char name[20]` (an array of characters of fixed size).

Answer (score 2):

The way you dynamically allocated that struct is correct:

```
struct Dimension* dim = malloc(sizeof(struct Dimensions));
```

> Also I would like then access the height and width variable in a loop later on in my code.

You should first assign some value to that `dim` first, something like:

```
dim->high = 1;
dim->width = 2;
```

The `name` member you just used a `char` which might not be what you need. Usually it's a string: `char name[100];`. You can't use assignment for that string though, so use `strcpy`.

Then you can access that later:

```
int h = dim->high;
```

Remember once you're done with the dynamically allocated memory, you should `free` it:

```
free(dim);
return 0;
```